# How can I make the background of an image appear transparent without PIL?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, transparent

I'm trying to make a GUI in tkinter that uses one image as an overlay on top of another, but when I place the image over the lower one, the transparent area of the image appears as grey.

I've searched for solutions to this, but all the results that I've found have pointed towards using PIL.

Is it possible for me to use transparent, or partially transparent images in the python tkinter module **without using PIL**?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some basic photoshop tools like the magic wand tool to remove the background, but keep in mind, some PNG format images have a faint background. This is either in the from of a watermark, or the image background was rendered with a lower opacity than the rest of the image. Your GUI may also have a layer placed above the images by default. Does it appear on each image seperatly when loaded into the GUI?